# Mapping object to array

Tags: javascript, mapping

Given an object like this:

```
{
  aaa: {
    text: "Text1",
    path: "Path1",
    type: "Type1"
  },
  bbb: {
    text: "Text2",
    path: "Path2",
    type: "Type2"
  },
...
}
```

What is the simplest way to return this array:

```
[
   {value: "aaa", label: "Text1"},
   {value: "bbb", label: "Text2"}
]
```

Do I have to loop through the object? I thought there might be a way with `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and explain what went wrong with your attempt (errors, unexpected results, etc.) Hint: [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) could help here

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array. Use `map` to loop and return the desired object.

```js
let obj = {
  aaa: {
    text: "Text1",
    path: "Path1",
    type: "Type1"
  },
  bbb: {
    text: "Text2",
    path: "Path2",
    type: "Type2"
  },
}

let result = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({value: k,label: v.text}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

this can help

```js
const obj = {
  aaa: {
    text: "Text1",
    path: "Path1",
    type: "Type1"
  },
  bbb: {
    text: "Text2",
    path: "Path2",
    type: "Type2"
  },
};
const ans = Object.keys(obj).map(itm => ({value: itm, title: obj[itm].text}))

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through those key values, use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method to get the key-value pair and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to iterate and generate the new array.

```js
let data = {"aaa":{"text":"Text1","path":"Path1","type":"Type1"},"bbb":{"text":"Text2","path":"Path2","type":"Type2"}};

let res = Object.entries(data).map(([value, { text: title }]) => ({ value, title }))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate the object and push the value in an array

```js
let obj = {
  aaa: {
    text: "Text1",
    path: "Path1",
    type: "Type1"
  },
  bbb: {
    text: "Text2",
    path: "Path2",
    type: "Type2"
  }
}
let modObj = [];

for (let keys in obj) {
  modObj.push({
    value: keys,
    label: obj[keys].text
  })
};

console.log(modObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one mentioned using both Object.keys and Object.values as you mentioned in the question ...

```js
var obj = {
  aaa: {
    text: "Text1",
    path: "Path1",
    type: "Type1"
  },
  bbb: {
    text: "Text2",
    path: "Path2",
    type: "Type2"
  }
};

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key, i){
  return {value: key, label: Object.values(obj)[i].text}
});

console.log(result);
```